# jquery get Child elements of <video> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video, video.js

I am working on changing the `src` attributes on the `<source>` elements inside my `<video>` element.

**Original Markup**

```
<video id='myVidID' class='video-js vjs-default-skin' controls autoplay preload='auto' width='1280' height='720' poster='poster.jpg' data-setup='{}'>

<source src='uploads/video/static/vid1.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
<source src='uploads/video/static/vid1.webm' type='video/webm'>

Whoops. Your browser does not Support HTML5 or Flash. Please upgrade your browser.

</video>
```

I want to:

Get the video container (element), and then reference child1, and then child2 (0,1).

My code seems to change the runtime added `src` attribute in the `<video>`  tag (`<video src=''`) instead of the two child source tags' `src` attributes.

P.S. My script runs, and does change the `src` attribute in the video tag (Which is not the intended change).

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var myVideo = videojs("myVidID");

function onComplete(){
var child = $('#myVidID').children();
child[0].src = 'uploads/video/demovid-01-02-2014.mp4';
child[1].src = 'uploads/video/demovid-01-02-2014.webm';

myVideo.load();
myVideo.play();
myVideo.off('ended', onComplete);
};

myVideo.on('ended', onComplete);

</script>
```

Comment: [Your code works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/hUZC8/), it changes the `src` property of the `source` elements.

Comment: Thanks for that... I used your input, and with that, determined that my videojs player seems to enclose the original video tag with a div with the original video id, and then appends a custom id to the video id. Looking for this new ID given to teh video element, I can find it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using [video.js](http://www.videojs.com), you'd be better off using its API to set the new source. That way it will also work if Flash fallback had to be used.

```
myPlayer.src([
  { type: "video/mp4", src: "uploads/video/demovid-01-02-2014.mp4" },
  { type: "video/webm", src: "uploads/video/demovid-01-02-2014.webm" }
]);
```

https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/api/vjs.Player.md#src-source-

Comment: Well that's convenient...! Thanks. Let me try it out.

Comment: You sir, made my day... I find the API docs layout extremely confusing. Maybe because I am a JS n00b. Thanks for that. Works a charm.